# HttpSendRequestA throws ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND (00002EE7)

Tags: c, http, send, simplehttpserver, getlasterror

I'm reverse engineering a piece of malware in Immunity Debugger and trying to connect it to a server I set up using Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` so I can download a file I put on there.

My call to `HttpSendRequestA` keeps failing, giving the error: `ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND (00002EE7)`. I understand that it means "the server name or address could not be resolved". However, I can access the server from a browser (it shows the file I put on the server, which I can click on and read) and I can see the requests as I visit the site (shown below). I have used ping `127.0.0.1` and ping `127.0.0.1:8000`, with the results shown below (the first works, the latter doesn't). I've tried accessing it in Immunity Debugger via `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.1:8000`, `https://127.0.0.1:8000/` and all yield the same result.

I am aware that `HttpSendRequestA` is part of several API calls (the list and order are [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/httpsendrequest-failed-error-code-2ee7-help-37152222.html)) and they are all in there. I've added the 3 function calls before hand since that's where I think the error is.

ping:

```
C:\Users\Daniel>ping 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\Daniel>ping 127.0.0.1:8000
Ping request could not find host 127.0.0.1:8000. Please check the name and try a
gain.
```

SimpleHTTPServer:

```
C:\Users\Daniel>cd Documents/
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents>cd tempServer
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\tempServer>dir
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 9C0B-05CE

Directory of C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\tempServer

02/21/2014  12:48 PM    <DIR>          .
02/21/2014  12:48 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/21/2014  12:48 PM                11 data.txt
           1 File(s)             11 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  31,708,946,432 bytes free

C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\tempServer>python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
WIN-NATUEANO3LL - - [23/Feb/2014 17:16:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
WIN-NATUEANO3LL - - [23/Feb/2014 17:20:10] "GET /data.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 -
WIN-NATUEANO3LL - - [23/Feb/2014 17:32:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
WIN-NATUEANO3LL - - [23/Feb/2014 17:32:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

code:

```
push    ebx             ; dwFlags          //0
push    ebx             ; lpszProxyBypass  //0
push    ebx             ; lpszProxy        //0
push    ebx             ; dwAccessType     //0
push    offset szAgent  ; "Windows+NT+5.1"
call    ds:Internet

push    ebx             ; dwContext        //0
push    400000h         ; dwFlags
mov     eax, offset szUserName
push    3               ; dwService
push    eax             ; lpszPassword     //0040B130
push    eax             ; lpszUserName     //0040B130
lea     eax, [ebp+szServerName]               
push    ebx             ; nServerPort      //000008000
push    eax             ; lpszServerName   //127.0.0.1
push    esi             ; hInternet        //handle to previous call
call    ds:InternetConnectA 

push    ebx                                         //0
push    4000000h        ; dwFlags
push    offset lpszAcceptTypes ; lplpszAcceptTypes
push    ebx             ; lpszReferrer              //0
lea     ecx, [ebp+fileToDownload] 
push    offset szPassword ; "HTTP/1.1"
push    ecx             ; lpszObjectName            //"/data.txt"
push    offset szVerb   ; "GET"                     
push    eax             ; hConnect                  //handle to previous call
call    ds:HttpOpenRequestA
```

Comment: Not directly related to your error, but... you cannot ping a TCP port. ping is actually a ICMP echo request. ICMP, TCP and UDP (and a few others) are all siblings in the IP family.

Comment: From my former comment, I'm guessing that you are using `127.0.0.1:8000` as the host name. But only `127.0.0.1` is the host name, the `:` is a separator and the `8000` is the port number. It would help if you could show us the code. Note that `InternetConnect()` has different parameters for the host name and the port number.

Comment: @rodrigo ok, added the the 2 calls before hand. I'm adding in their values in comments now

Comment: You claim that `nServerPort` 000008000. Is that 0x8000 (aka 32768)? Because your server is listening at decimal 8000?